# how to convert ISO date format 2020-02-22T00:00:00+01:00 and extract year using datetime with python?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

The documentation of the API i am fetching the date from states:

> All date/time properties are specified in ISO 8601 format, e.g. YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ (time in UTC) or YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS+hh:mm (where hh:mm specifies the time offset from UTC). Not specifying timezone information is valid but the result is undefined.

When i try to convert using datetime.fromisoformat it gives med error saying 'value must be str' even though it is a string value.

```
    closed_date = data['closeddate'] 
    print('closeddate: ', closed_date) ##outputs: 2020-02-22T00:00:00+01:00

    convertedDate = datetime.fromisoformat(closed_date).date()
    year = convertedDate.year
```

output value:

> 2020-02-22T00:00:00+01:00

But it works when a date is in this format:

> 2020-06-15T13:18:23.040000+02:00

I also tried :

```
convertedDateOfDeal = datetime.strptime(closed_date, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
```

But this gave me the error:

> ValueError: unconverted data remains: +02:00

How to convert the remaining: '+02:00' which represents the time difference ??

Comment: what is data['closeddate'] ?

Comment: Thats just a string value I fetch from an API.

Comment: are you sure it's a string, what does `print(repr(closed_date))` give you?

Comment: it gives me same output as above with quotes '2019-06-05T00:00:00+02:00 '

Comment: ok so now i replaced an empty space with T and now gives me error :

ValueError: unconverted data remains: +02:00.  How to convert the rest '+02:00' ????

Comment: Why are you going through so much trouble just to get the year?  `int(closed_date.split('-')[0])` would do the trick.

Comment: year = int(closed_date.split('-')[0]) 

gave me error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Then you lied to us about what `closed_date` contains, it's actually `None`.  You need to fix that first.

Comment: Why would i lie? that is what it prints out on the terminal.  read the snippet from the documentation above which states: 'Not specifying timezone information is valid but the result is undefined',  maybe this is the problem? How do I specify timezone e.g Europe-London?

Comment: When I use `closed_date='2020-02-22T00:00:00+01:00'`, `int(closed_date.split('-')[0])` returns `2020`.  The only way to get a `NoneType` error is when `closed_date=None`, which contradicts everything else you've claimed so far.

Comment: when I use print(type(closed_date)) with limit query multiple values it gives me a mix of <class 'str'> and nontype, so I think you're right! I am lying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that some of the data i Fetched was null so to fix this issue I checked if each data was a string value before converting:

```
    if isinstance(closed_date, str):
        converted_date = datetime.fromisoformat(closed_date).date()

        year = converted_date.year
```